# Keybinding to return to homepage in conkeror?

Tags: conkeror

I have set my default homepage in my conkerorrc and conkeror opens with it fine.
`homepage = "/home/dka/my-home-page/index.html";`
How do i get back to my homepage after I have browsed to another page?
Is there a default keybinding or do I have to set one? Seems stupid if there is none built in!

Answer (score 0):

well I couldn't find a default keybinding so I just made a webjump
`define_webjump("hp", "/home/dka/my-home-page/index.html"); //HOME`
so I just type `g hp`